# edit screen column, line, buffer

Tags: command-line, size, buffer

Right now I use `mode con: cols=40 lines=5` in simple batch scripts to change the screen size since it doesn't need to be that big, but in some cases, the data goes off screen and I need a buffer size. I was wondering if there is another command to reset the command line window to default view like when you open it normally?

Comment: why not `mode con: col=80 lines=24`? ?? Good luck.

Comment: Well I wanted the command prompt to open in a small window for input, then grow into a bigger window after input is entered, but if I use the 'mode con' I can't make a huge buffer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by buffer size. The buffer set under cmd.exe->properties->options or screen buffer size set under cmd.exe->properties->Layout ? Unfortunately, `help mode` doesn't show anything that looks like it will help. I recommend that you note the small number of 'followers' for your size and buffer tags, and change them out for tags with large number of followers, like WINDOWS or WINDOWS-BATCH. Good luck.

Comment: I know how to set the buffer size, etc with the Properties. But I want to do it during a script not just for the command prompt on my computer. The script will be run on different systems not just my own, so setting it for myself won't be any good.

Comment: my point is, is that your question is currently ambiguous. So please specify which buffer you need to set in your automation, and please edit that info into your question. Good luck.

Comment: Well currently the 'lines' part of that bit is the buffer, but if I make it a high number like 200 or 500, it will resize the window to that. With the regular command prompt, when you set a buffer via properties, it adds a scrollbar for you to use.